# AndroidStudio import only the first level of a package

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

For clarity in my code I would like android studio to import only the first level of a certain package.

In my structure I have (letter are class):

```
A
| ---- B
| -----| --C
| ---- D
```

If I want to use a function in class C android studio will do this import:`import "A.B.C"` automatically and in my code I will call my function like this 
`a = myfunction()`.

But I would like him to make this import automatically `import "A"`and that in my code I can use my function like this`a = B.C.myfunction()`.

I know how to do it manually but I would like it to be automatic with the autocompletion, that it does not propose for the moment with the name of packages

Comment: Usually the import are auto-managed when working with Android Studio, but you can change the imports manually to what you desire..